# TypeError: cupcake_flour() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cu_flour'. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my first time taking python and i'm having a hard time understanding what I've done wrong to receive this error? This code is supposed to change grams to cups for a cupcake recipe and this is just the first step converting the flour. The input function works but after that I get the above error.

```
user = input("How many cookies do you want to make? ")

def cupcake_flour(cu_flour):
  cu_flour = user * 100 / 120

  print(cu_flour + "cups of flour")

def main(): 
   cupcake_flour()

main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok everyone posted a solution fixing the main issue, but no one bothed to make your function really usable. As a general rule, you want to clearly separate your "domain model" (the things you compute, the rules that apply to those things etc) from the user interface part. IOW, your `cupcake_flour` should not print anything but *return* a value and let the UI part do the printing:

```
# this is your domain model
def cupcake_flour(cookies):
  return cookies * 100 / 120

# this is your UI, which gather inputs from the user,
# convert/sanitisze them, pass them to the domain model,
# and display the (formatted) result to the user.
def main():
   num_cookies = int(input("How many cookies do you want to make? "))
   cu_flour = cupcake_flour(num_cookies)
   print("for {} coookies you'll need {} cups of flour".format(num_cookies, cu_flour))

# only execute main if the file is invoked as a script
# so you can also import it in another script
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have defined your function `cupcake_flour` to take an argument, but you are not providing one when you are calling `cupcake_flour()`. You probably want to pass the user input to the function and then print the amount of flour needed like so:

```
def cupcake_flour(cookies):
  cu_flour = cookies * 100 / 120

  print(str(cu_flour) + "cups of flour")

def main():
   num_cookies = int(input("How many cookies do you want to make? "))
   cupcake_flour(num_cookies)

main()
```

Note a few minor changes:

1. `int(input("How many cookies do you want to make? "))` since the input is supposed to be interpreted as a number (and used as such in the calculation)
2. Moved the user input into the main, as it makes more sense to only ask for it when `main()` is called
3. `str(cu_flour)` as it needs to be a string

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your help. So I tried running your code but I get an error on the print statement. should i add an int or float to it?

Comment: line 12, in cupcake_flour
    print(cu_flour + "cups of flour")

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

Comment: See edit. If you want to concatenate a number with a string you need to convert the number to a string

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what the error says: `def cupcake_flour(cu_flour)` says that `cupcake_flour` requires an argument `cu_flour`. But you're calling it without any argument. You should replace `def cupcake_flour(cu_flour)` with `def cupcake_flour()`.

Comment: Thank you! That worked but I get an error on the calculation cu_flour = user * 100 / 120. I'm not sure if i have to use // for the division or if i need to identify that it is an int or float

Answer (score 0):

The cause of your current error is defining the function "cupcake_flour" which takes the argument "cu_flour" and then calling that function without passing the argument.

In addition the variable "user" will not be accessible within the function. The "user" variable is not passed to the function but even if it was it will default to a string so your multiplication won't work.

As far as I can see this is probably what you were trying to do.

```
def cupcake_flour(cookie_number):
    flower_required = cookie_number * 100 / 120
    print(str(flower_required) + " cups of flour")



def main():
    cookie_number = int(input("how many cookies do you want to make? "))
    cupcake_flour(cookie_number)

main()
```

Comment: In Python, functions can access variables in the main environment. It's perhaps poor programming practice to not explicitly pass a variable, but it won't throw an error.